# PHP output echoed out of order

Tags: php, html, mariadb

I'm having trouble with the output order of a stored procedure (MariaDB). I've tried this several different ways and each echoed result set exhibits the same problem. (I couldn't resolve it using procedural/mysqli, so remade the project in PDO, and now the same issue has arisen.) This is epic, so thanks to everyone who reads.

I'm trying to create a form-letter report for each member in the result set, with an introduction and a table of fees attributed to that member.

So I would expect to see:

Intro for Member 1,
Table for Member 1;
Intro for Member 2,
Table for Member 2; and so on.

The problem is that I am seeing:

Intro for Member 1,
Intro for Member 2,
Table for Member 1,
Intro for Member 3,
Table for Member 2,
Intro for Member 4,
Table for Member 3; and so on.

Called stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM `View_Accounts_report`  WHERE `Date` >= parameter_start_date  AND `Date` <= parameter_end_dated
```

Call to the output function within html:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        Accounts_by_date($_REQUEST['start_date'], $_REQUEST['end_date']);
    }
```

php function Accounts_by_date method 1:

```
function Accounts_by_date($start_date, $end_date) {
        require '../lib/pdo.php';


$prev = NULL;

$sql = "CALL accounts_report_dates (:start_date, :end_date)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':start_date', $start_date);
$stmt->bindValue(':end_date', $end_date);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($results);

$arrlength = count($results);

for ($row = 0; $row < $arrlength; $row++) {

    $person = $results[$row]['Member_ID'];    // tracking each row

    if ($person != $prev) {    // if the current member is different from the previous member, print header and row

// table headers

        echo "<br><br>Member: " . $results[$row]['Member_name'] . "<br>";
        echo "Dear " . $results[$row]['First_name'] . ",<br>";
        echo "Please find your Belmont Pottery Group fees for the period " . $start_date . " to " . $end_date . " below. <br>";
        echo "<br><table><tr><th>Total</th><th>Member_ID</th><th>Date</th><th>Transaction</th><th>Amount</th>";
        echo "<th>First name</th><th>Email</th><th>Member name</th></tr>";

// table rows

        echo "<tr><td>" . $results[$row]['Total'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['Member_ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['Date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['Transaction'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>$" . $results[$row]['Amount'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['First_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['Email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['Member_name'] . "</td></tr>";

        $prev = $person;

    }else{

        echo "<tr><td>" . $results[$row]['Total'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['Member_ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['Date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['Transaction'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>$" . $results[$row]['Amount'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['First_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['Email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $results[$row]['Member_name'] . "</td></tr>";

        $prev = $person;

    }
}
```

}

Excerpt of var_dump from php function method 1:

> array(15) { [0]=> array(8) { ["Total"]=> string(5) "36.00" ["Member_ID"]=> int(31) ["Date"]=> string(10) "2017-11-06" ["Transaction"]=> string(4) "Clay" ["Amount"]=> string(5) "18.00" ["First_name"]=> string(6) "Dummy " ["Email"]=> string(25) "dummy@dummy.com" ["Member_name"]=> string(12) "Dummy Nine " } [1]=> array(8) { ["Total"]=> string(5) "36.00" ["Member_ID"]=> int(31) ["Date"]=> string(10) "2017-11-13" ["Transaction"]=> string(4) "Clay" ["Amount"]=> string(5) "18.00" ["First_name"]=> string(6) "Dummy " ["Email"]=> string(25) "dummy@dummy.com" ["Member_name"]=> string(12) "Dummy Nine " } [2]=> array(8) { ["Total"]=> string(5) "40.20" ["Member_ID"]=> int(29) ["Date"]=> string(10) "2017-11-05" ["Transaction"]=> string(6) "Firing" ["Amount"]=> string(4) "3.70" ["First_name"]=> string(6) "Dummy " ["Email"]=> string(25) "dummy@dummy.com" ["Member_name"]=> string(13) "Dummy Seven " } [3]=> array(8) { ["Total"]=> string(5) "40.20" ["Member_ID"]=> int(29) ["Date"]=> string(10) "2017-11-05" ["Transaction"]=> string(10) "Attendance" ["Amount"]=> string(4) "4.00" ["First_name"]=> string(6) "Dummy " ["Email"]=> string(25) "dummy@dummy.com" ["Member_name"]=> string(13) "Dummy Seven " }

php function Accounts_by_date method 2:

```
function Accounts_by_date($start_date, $end_date) {
        require '../lib/pdo.php';


$prev = NULL;

$sql = "CALL accounts_report_dates (:start_date, :end_date)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':start_date', $start_date);
$stmt->bindValue(':end_date', $end_date);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bindColumn('Total', $total);
$stmt->bindColumn('Member_ID', $id);
$stmt->bindColumn('Date', $date);
$stmt->bindColumn('Transaction', $transaction);
$stmt->bindColumn('Amount', $amount);
$stmt->bindColumn('First_name', $fname);
$stmt->bindColumn('Email', $email);
$stmt->bindColumn('Member_name', $name);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {

    $person = $id;

    if ($person != $prev) {    // if the current member is different from the previous member, print header and row

// table headers

        echo "<br><br>Member: " . $name . "<br>";
        echo "Dear " . $fname . ",<br>";
        echo "Please find your Belmont Pottery Group fees for the period " . $start_date . " to " . $end_date . " below. <br><br>";
        echo "The total of your invoice is: $" . $total . "<br>";
        echo "<br><table><tr><th>Total</th><th>Member_ID</th><th>Date</th><th>Transaction</th><th>Amount</th>";
        echo "<th>First name</th><th>Email</th><th>Member name</th></tr>";

// table rows

        echo "<tr><td>" . $total . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $date . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $transaction . "</td>";
        echo "<td>$" . $amount . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $fname . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $email . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $name . "</td></tr>";

        $prev = $person;

    }else{

        echo "<tr><td>" . $total . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $date . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $transaction . "</td>";
        echo "<td>$" . $amount . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $fname . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $email . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $name . "</td></tr>";

        $prev = $person;

    }
}
```

}

var_dump of php function method 2 returns true.

Output (both methods):

Member: Dummy Nine
Dear Dummy ,
Please find your BPG fees for the period 2017-11-01 to 2017-11-30 below.

Member: Dummy Seven
Dear Dummy ,
Please find your BPG fees for the period 2017-11-01 to 2017-11-30 below.

Total   Member_ID   Date    Transaction Amount  First name  Email   Member name
36.00   31  2017-11-06  Clay    $18.00  Dummy   dummy@dummy.com Dummy Nine
36.00   31  2017-11-13  Clay    $18.00  Dummy   dummy@dummy.com Dummy Nine

Member: Dummy Six
Dear Dummy ,
Please find your BPG fees for the period 2017-11-01 to 2017-11-30 below.

Total   Member_ID   Date    Transaction Amount  First name  Email   Member name
40.20   29  2017-11-05  Firing  $3.70   Dummy   dummy@dummy.com Dummy Seven
40.20   29  2017-11-05  Attendance  $4.00   Dummy   dummy@dummy.com Dummy Seven
40.20   29  2017-11-19  Firing  $11.60  Dummy   dummy@dummy.com Dummy Seven

Member: Dummy Three
Dear Dummy ,
Please find your BPG fees for the period 2017-11-01 to 2017-11-30 below.

Total   Member_ID   Date    Transaction Amount  First name  Email   Member name
26.60   28  2017-11-02  Attendance  $4.00   Dummy   dummy@dummy.com Dummy Six
26.60   28  2017-11-06  Attendance  $4.00   Dummy   dummy@dummy.com Dummy Six
26.60   28  2017-11-03  Firing  $17.00  Dummy   dummy@dummy.com Dummy Six
26.60   28  2017-11-06  Firing  $1.60   Dummy   dummy@dummy.com Dummy Six

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start by making sure you are closing your tables, you can add the code below:

```
if ($person != $prev) {
    if ($row > 0) echo "</table>"; /*added line of code*/
```

That should fix some issues with multiple table header cells in the same table. The multiple 's in one table are pushing your intro's up to the top.

Don't forget to add a

```
</table>
```

to the end of your code as well after the while loop is done for proper html

Comment: Thank you! Embarrassingly, that was the problem.

Comment: @E.rex glad I could help. I didn't see anything else will wrong with your code